# How to render a .mht file inside an iframe

Tags: html, headless-browser, mhtml

I want to take a snapshot of a page using headless chrome which will return a file to me, so I am creating an mht file as it will contain more information about the web page. So, now I want to render this snapshot inside an iframe but I am unable to do so.

```
<iframe src="file:///home/user/untitled1.mht"></iframe>
```

This is returning an error after it is rendered.

```
Attempted to load a multipart archive into an subframe
```

Comment: hi @IamSaquib, did u find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The loading of the content of an MHTML file inside an iframe is technically not possible for security reasons. Instead of re-hashing, here is the [answer directly from a developer working on the Chromium project](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=416812).

The alternative way is to dynamically load the HTML's content inside an iframe. This will NOT create any CORS issue as this is not technically linking directly to a third-party website URL.

Main HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div>an iframe</div>
<iframe id="f1" width="100%" height="800px"></iframe>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS file(test.js):

```
const htmlContent = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<strong>Hello World</strong>
</body>
</html>
`
const htmlblob = new Blob([htmlContent], {
  type: "text/html"
});
const frame = document.querySelector("#f1");

frame.src = URL.createObjectURL(htmlblob);
```

Alternatively, here's a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyderb/nmtq8wv3/3/).